# Duplicate but original is out-of-date

Tags: discussion

The new question [Bone to mesh - convert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190319/bone-to-mesh-convert/) is pretty much a duplicate of [Convert bones to meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75040/convert-bones-to-meshes/). The new question is asking for something a little bit different, but it appears [@lemon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19156/lemon) anticipated that as there is commented out code in the original answer to do what the new user wants.

My question has two parts:

1. The original answer is for Blender 2.79 won't run under 2.8x. Should I make the edits to the original answer's script, add a second script in the original answer, or put the updated script in the new question?
2. I think a GUI to ask about bones shape would be a good improvement to the original script. If I do add a GUI,  Should I make the edits to the original answer's script, add a second script in the original answer, or put the updated script in the new question?

Comment: So I ended up making the needed edits to the original script, and added the UI version as an answer to the second question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update. If it is a simple and most importantly backwards compatible update it should probably be an edit to the original post. If you made major changes and significant improvements to the script it may warrant a new answer so feel free to post. You may even gain some deserved reputation for it. Don't forget to credit the original author, and link to the post containing the source script

Comment: My general advice is to *not* overwrite the original answer, but to either add a 2.8 section to the existing answer, leaving the original code intact, or add a new answer.